# How to popluat value form database into combo box using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I want to fetch list of students into combo box and on the base of combo box slection I will fetch their related record into another grid. please guide me regarding this task.

Comment: what do you have already? code? structure of database tables? some ORM?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind DropDownList as below

```
DropDownList1.DataSource=GetStudentDataSet();
DropDownList1.DataTextField="StudentName";
DropDownList1.DataValueField="StudentID";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Put GridView bind code on selected change event of DropDownList as below

```
void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Fecth selected student id 
         int studentId = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        //Bind Grdivew
    }
```

Comment: I have database only and I want to fetch only name from student table in dropdown list,, then after fetching name, on change drop down I wana to fetch particular record related to that selected student

Comment: int studentname = Convert.ToInt32(ddstd.SelectedValue);
it gives FormatException, Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @Touseef:If you want to fetch Student name then there is no need to convert to int.Simply collect the selected value in string variable like **string studentname=DropDownList1.SelectedValue;**